# Pandas concatenate all elements of dataframe into single series

Tags: python, pandas

There must be a simple answer to this, but for some reason I can't find it. Apologies if this is a duplicate question.

I have a dataframe with shape on the order of (1000,100). I want to concatenate ALL items in the dataframe into a single series (or list). Order doesn't matter (so it doesn't matter what axis to concatenate along). I don't want/need to keep any column names or indices. Dropping NaNs and duplicates is ok but not required.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will yield a 1-dim numpy-array of the lowest-common dtype for all elements.

```
df.values.ravel()
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the quick response! Most elements in my dataframe are strings, so I ended up converting it right back to a pandas series to continue working with it.